# Como faço ao preencher uma combo eu preencho o Value dela com wpf e c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Fiz esse código para preencher uma combobox. Funciona perfeitamente, porém eu preciso além do texto a ser apresentado na combo, precisa também carregar uma espécie de Value, como fazemos na web onde temos o Name e o Value. Eu uso WPF. Se eu preencher a combo em design time assim:

```
<ComboBoxItem Content="Milho" Name="M"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Soja" Name="S"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Feijão" Name="F"/>
```

Veja que o name funciona como um Value e consigo pegar esse valor no code behind. Esse é code para preencher a combo em runtime:

```
public void CarregaComboSecagem()
        {
            ListaSecagens lista = new ListaSecagens();
            ObservableCollection<string> listaCtg;

            var prod = lista.listaSecagens();

            listaCtg = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            foreach (var prd in prod)
            {
                listaCtg.Add(prd.Umidade.ToString());
            }

            cbxSecagem.ItemsSource = listaCtg;

        }
```

Prod é a listaSecagem:

```
public class ListaSecagens
    {
        private SiloContext contexto = new SiloContext();

        public List<Secagem> listaSecagens()
        {
            return contexto.Secagens.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Minha entity Secagem

```
[Table("Secagem")]
    public class Secagem
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int IdSecagem { get; set; }
        public int IdProduto { get; set; }
        public decimal Umidade { get; set; }
        public decimal Desconto { get; set; }
        public decimal Valor_Sec { get; set; }
    }
```

Meu context

```
public class SiloContext : DbContext
    {
        public SiloContext()
            : base("SiloConn")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<SiloContext>(null);
        }
        public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Balanca> Balancas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Secagem> Secagens { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: qual o tipo de `prod` ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, editei o post e coloquei a classe listaSecagem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque o source do combo, como a lista de seus objetos, depois você acessa o objeto selecionado com a propriedade `SelectedValue`. Exemplo:

No seu caso, conforme me explicou no chat, você deve preencher o combo de produtos no evento Loaded da Window. Quando o usuário escolher um item, você deve disparar o evento SelectionChanged do combo de produtos, e carregar o combo de Secagem. Seu código deve estar semelhante a este:

```
    private void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxProduto.ItemsSource = ProdutoDAO.GetProdutos(); //Seu método que retorna a List<Produto>
        comboBoxProduto.DisplayMemberPath = "Nome";
    }

    private void comboBoxProduto_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBoxProduto.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            comboBoxSecagem.ItemsSource = SecagemDAO.GetSecagem(((Produto)comboBoxProduto.SelectedValue).Id);
            comboBoxSecagem.DisplayMemberPath = "Umidade";
        }
        else
            comboBoxSecagem.ItemsSource = null;
    }
```

Classes de Exemplo

```
public class Secagem
{
    public int IdSecagem { get; set; }
    public int IdProduto { get; set; }
    public decimal Umidade { get; set; }
    public decimal Desconto { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor_Sec { get; set; }
}

public class SecagemDAO
{
    public static List<Secagem> GetSecagem(int idProduto)
    {
        //codigo de selecionar a lista de acordo com o produto
        //return Context.Select(...Where...) //Exemplo!!!
        return new List<Secagem>();
    }

}

public class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

}

public class ProdutoDAO
{
    public static List<Produto> GetProdutos()
    {
        //codigo do Select dos produtos
        //return Context.Select(...Where...) //Exemplo!!!
        return new List<Produto>(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: No caso acima, você preencheu a combo manualmente. No meu caso, que vem de um BD, terei que criar uma espécie de Chave/Valor e a chave eu apresento na combo e o valor seria meu "value", certo?

Comment: editado, veja se ajuda

Comment: Alguma coisa que ainda não entendi, deixa eu tentar fazer, mas ainda to meio confuso

Comment: o source do combo, será uma lista de objetos, da sua classe e não uma lista de string, quando você acessa o `SelectedValue` você acessa o objeto que está selecionado, com todos os seus valores. Editei novamente a resposta

Comment: Rodei antes dessa atualização e na combo não veio os valores corretos, tipo, deveria vir: Soja, Milho, Feijão e etc e veio Domain.Entities.Umidade. Me desculpe-me, mas não entendi nada

Comment: faltou essa parte: `cbxSecagem.DisplayMemberPath = "Umidade";`

Comment: Tá dando erro nas vars que vc criou. Se eu retirar, consigo trazer na combo os dados, mas não consigo o value, pois não setei ele.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63872/discussion-between-rovann-linhalis-and-pnet).